# How can I get a navigation bar button to segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController that points to a UIViewController. In that UIViewController, I want the right button of the navigationitem to be a .Add UIBarButtonItem which segues to another scene called "nextScene".

It's my understanding that I need to have the action be the "performSegueWithidentifier" method if I want to create this segue programmatically. Here is what I have:

`let plusButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "performSegueWithIdentifier:")

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(plusButton, animated: true)`

What is the proper syntax for getting to another scene called "nextScene"? How should my performSegueWithidentifier method handle this?

EDIT:
Getting the following error: unrecognized selector sent to instance ... 2015-08-06 07:57:18.534 ..[...] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[... goToSegue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ....

Here is the code I'm using for the segue:

```
let plusButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "goToSegue:")`

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(plusButton, animated: true) }

func goToSegue() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segueName", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just control + drag from your UIBarButtonItem to the UIViewController (or other type of controller) in your Storyboard.

[image]

If you want to do it through code you'll need to backup your action call with a method in your target class that can handle it. performSegueWithIdentifier is a default method for your view controller so I would call another function that then calls performSegueWithIdentifier, like this:

```
let plusButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "plusBttnTouched:")

func plusBttnTouched(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "segueNameHere", sender: self)

}
```

Here's an updated code example:

Storyboard:

[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create bar button item

    let plusButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: Selector("plusBttnTouched:"))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [plusButton]

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: - Actions

func plusBttnTouched(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("plusViewController", sender: self)
    })

}

}
```

Using a sender in your method parameter allows you to access the instance of the defined type within your method. You say you want this when you add a : to the end of your selector, it is not required.

Comment: I've tried that without success, probably because I did not make "sender" a parameter for "plusBttnTouched". Could you explain to me the role of "sender" here? Also, could you explain the difference between using it through the interface and through code? When I try and drag it onto the navigation bar, it doesn't appear.

Comment: Sorry I mean Control drag

Comment: Getting the following error (code I'm using placed in original post): `unrecognized selector sent to instance ... 2015-08-06 07:57:18.534 ..[...] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[... goToSegue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

Comment: remove the : where you call goToSegue

Answer (score 5):

1. Create segue between `UIViewController` (Right click on `firstViewController` and drag it to `secondviewcontroller`)

[image: Right Click on view controller and drag it to second view controller]

[image: select segue action]

2. Give identifier name to that `segue`

[image: Give Identifier name]

3. perform `segue` with that `segue` name

Now in order to perform segue using `UIBarButtonItem` add following code in `viewDidLoad` method to `firstViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "navigateToNextViewController")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Now create `navigateToNextViewController` Method and perform segue from that method

```
func navigateToNextViewController(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goNext", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Any idea what's causing this? `unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
2015-08-06 07:57:18.534 ..[...] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[... goToSegue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

Comment: @Brandon It cannot find the method specify in `selector` parameter

Comment: @Brandon How you calling that segue method?