# Create a show segue from a button in nav bar towards a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a button in nav bar , when user click it , we move to the next view controller page. It has some validations in form when all the validation are fulfill than we move to next page.I'm confused that how can i programatically create a show segue on this button in nav bar.I want to create it because i want to take the value from this page towards the second one through segue.How can i do this?

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@""
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(rightBtnClicked)];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]];
rightButton.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Here is rightBtnClicked method

```
-(void)rightBtnClicked:(id)sender{
[self Validation];
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Submit" sender:sender];
NSLog(@"Am here");
SubmitImageViewController *secondVC = [[SubmitImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Images" bundle:nil];
secondVC.tites=Title.text;
secondVC.propfor=_but1.titleLabel.text;
secondVC.proptype=_but2.titleLabel.text; //secondVC's variable to which u wanna pass value to
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:true];
```

}

Comment: try my answer using `prepareforsegue` Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show segue is nothing more than pushing a new VC to your VC's navigation stack.

If you are not using storyboard and want to do it programmatically you can do

```
let secondVC = CViewController(nibName: "your_nib_name", bundle: nil)
secondVC.params = value
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

You don't need prepareForSegue to get the access to second VC because u already have a VC which you are pushing :)

**EDIT:**

As OP asked for Objective-C code updating my answer

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secondVC.params = value; //secondVC's variable to which u wanna pass value to
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:true];
```

**EDIT #2:**

As OP is facing crash am updating my answer to show how to write selector to `UIBarButtonItem` action

You should write the method rightButtonClicked in the same class where you are adding the bar button to Navigation bar.

For example : If you are adding button in `ViewController.m` then write

```
-(void)rightBtnClicked {
    NSLog(@"Am here");
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondVC.params = value; //secondVC's variable to which u wanna pass value to
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:true];
}
```

**EDIT #3:**

Fixing the bug in OP's code

change

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@""
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(rightBtnClicked)];
```

to

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@""
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(rightBtnClicked:)];
```

Look the way we are calling rightBtnClicked with colon.

**EDIT #4:**

As OP's isn't aware of how to instantiate VC from storyboard updating my answer

Step1 : Set the storyboard Identifier for your `SubmitImageViewController`
Open your storyboard, select the `SubmitImageViewController` and set the class and storyboard id as shown below.

[image]

Look carefully the Storyboard id "submitImageVC" string.

**Step 2:**

Now instantiate VC from storyboard using this storyboard id

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"submitImageVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:true];
```

Please specify the proper storyboard name and storyboard id and u'll be fine to go :)

Comment: sure buddy Gimme a minute :)

Comment: @umer : See my updated answer and please consider accepting it, if it helped :)

Comment: This code i have to write in my that page in which i have nav bar button? @Sandeep Bhandari

Comment: You have to write it in rightBtnClicked method which gets called when button is tapped :)

Comment: im getting a error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SubmitPropViewController rightBtnClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc01a40f560'
. @Sandeep Bhandari

Comment: @umer : Where have you written ur method rightBtnClicked ? Can u update ur question with the code and also mention file name

Comment: @umer : Updated my answer please have a look

Comment: i have edited my question check that. @Sandeep Bhandari

Comment: Bro im gettinng error when i fill the form and click the nav bar button. his is the error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/23D54E17-36FB-4397-BA5E-09A05EB0EBF3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2BCFB6AD-2C20-4DCB-B4B2-1E28250664EB/PK.House.app> (loaded)' with name 'Images''. @Sandeep Bhandari

Comment: @umer : That means iOS is trying to find the nib in the main bundle and it cant find it :) You have specified the nib name as "Images" nib name is nothing but the name of .xib file. If you have created xib for your SecondVC write that name in [[SubmitImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Images" bundle:nil];

Comment: If its a storyboard, load the VC using storyboard identifier and finally if there is no xib or storyboard to SubmitImageViewController VC then simply say [[SubmitImageViewController alloc] init] in SubmitImageViewController override init, load nib and add the view as subview. You can choose whichever makes more sense to you

Comment: i'm using storyboard what i have to write now? @Sandeep Bhandari

Comment: @umer : Always welcome buddy :) Wanna know how to create the segue as well as mentioned in other answer ? I can show u that as well :) But I din prefer it because it won't work if your VC's are in different story boards :) Thats the drawback :)

Comment: Okay i get it. @Sandeep Bhandari

Answer (score 0):

In Selector method :

```
-(IBAction)rightBtnClicked:(id)sender{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:sender];
    }
```

Simply grab a reference to the target view controller in prepareForSegue: method and pass any objects you need to there. Implement       `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;`

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"]){
            SecondViewController * secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
            secondVC.params = value; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is delegate in it. @Shailesh

Comment: sorry for that...i was using it in my code while unwinding that segue.

Comment: It's also worth noticing that you can create a segue from view controller to view controller. It doesn't need to be "attached" to a particular `UIView` subclass (like a `UIButton` or so).

Comment: getting an error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SubmitPropViewController rightBtnClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8dc7525ac0'
. @Shailesh

Comment: @umer have u created segue  ? and gave that segue identifier name ? and destination controller as ur secondVC name?

Comment: How can i create it from a button in nav bar? It is not showing me button in storyboard. @Shailesh

Comment: u can  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845915/how-can-i-get-a-navigation-bar-button-to-segue>